# How can I prevent unused HDs from turning on all the time?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory

I'm using a desktop `x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)` platform with 32 GB working memory and a Synology DS212J with 3 TB space. In the workstation I have a SD drive for system and programs with just a 16 MB swap file, and a conventional 300 GB HD for archiving purposes  with 30 GB reserved for a 24 GB swap. The latter comes only to account when I'm doing huge calculations (or programming errors).

[image]

My problem is, very often I have to wait for the conventional HD to turn on, which I can tell by hearing an upward sweep sound and the system freezes in the meanwhile. I'm not sure when this is the case, Agent Ransack tells me that there are *no* changed files today, but the incident happened the last time a few minutes ago.

This is quite annoying, and also I can't understand this behavior, because I'm neither using the swap file nor the other space which serves only as an archive.

I hope I have included all relevant information.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that this still happens even after _disabling_ the swap file on that disk?

Comment: @grawity Ok, disabled now. How would I test on the fly if it has an impact?

Comment: Wait the usual amount of time for the problem to re-occur, then wait a 2nd time (and maybe 3rd), and if it hasn't reoccured in that period, then the change probably has had an impact.

Comment: Ok. What will happen if my 32GB ram are exceeded w/o swap file?

Comment: The OS will kill the program with the most memory use. Are you saying, though, that your 32GB of memory _was_ being exceeded during the time when you noticed the HDD turning on?

Comment: No, as stated in my question that hardly ever happens.